# I am trying to remove/purge all reoccurring terms from a list in LISP

Tags: lisp

I am new to LISP apparently... I am writing a function that takes a list and returns that list with all the duplicates removed, so  (myPurge '(p a c e p c))->(a e p c)

***This is my (edited)code:***

```
(defun myPurge (L)

    (if (eq L nil)         ;if empty return nil

        nil
        (if(eq (car L)(car(cdr L)) )   ;if I find a match call function on  
                                   ;rest of list
            (myPurge (cdr L))
                                   ;else return that term and than call on 
          (progn                              ;rest of list
            (car L)                        
            (myPurge(cdr L)) ))))
```

***BUTTTTTTTT, when I call this function I get `NIL`!
***:

***Why am i getting `NIL` instead of it returning `car L` ?***

******Thank you all, this is my finished code that I ended up using( it uses another function 'myMember'  I defined earlier.******

`(defun myPurge (L)
        (if (eq L nil)
                nil
                (if(myMember(car L)(cdr L))
                        (myPurge(cdr L))
                (cons (car L)(myPurge(cdr L))))))))`

****here is myMember*****it returns true if X is a member of L

`(defun myMember (X L)
        (if(eq L nil)
                nil
                (if(eq X(car L))
                t
                (myMember X(cdr L)) )) )`

Comment: It is a good idea to better format your code. Then it should be easy to see how you use IF. See how the syntax of IF is defined and how many subforms are allowed.

Comment: WHat is wrong with the format , is it not legible?

Comment: It's not correctly indented.

Comment: It has been reformatted and edited. I am not sure how to return a list without the duplicates!

Comment: But it's still not correctly indented. Why are the two IFs on the same column? It's basically VERY VERY hard to write code in a language using nested lists, if these lists are not indented correctly. You really need to get this right first. Usually this is not a problem, since the text editor should be able select and indent Lisp expressions.

Comment: Since it's obvious the result is a list where it's the `cons` that makes the result with the element that shouldn't be removed? Also you are just comparing two elements so the result can still have duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

After reformatting your code looks like this:

```
(defun myPurge (L)
  (if (eq L nil)
    nil
    (if (eq (car L) (car (cdr L)))
      (myPurge (cdr L))
      (car L)
      (myPurge (cdr L)))))
```

As you can see, the last `if` is called with 4 arguments. But `if` only takes 3 arguments (condition, then-part, else-part).

Comment: can you suggest how i would do two things in the `else` part?

Comment: @user3799901 I don't use Lisp but `progn` would probably work.

Comment: @user3799901 That's because your function either returns `nil` directly or calls itself recursively (`(myPurge (cdr L))` in the two branches), so the only thing it can return is `nil`.

Comment: `(defun myPurge (L)
        (if (eq L nil)
        nil
        (if(eq (car L)(car(cdr L)) )
        (myPurge (cdr L))
        (progn
        (car L)
        (myPurge(cdr L)) ))))

Comment: 1st iteration , p != a , so why doesnt it go into `else` and print  `car L` and than call itself?

Comment: @user3799901 There's no `print` in your code. You call `(car L)` but do nothing with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
(defun myPurge (L)

    (if (eq L nil)         ;if empty return nil

        nil
    (if(eq (car L)(car(cdr L)) )   ;if I find a match call function on rest 
                                   ;of list
        (myPurge (cdr L))
                                   ;else return that term and than call on 
    (progn                              ;rest of list
        (car L)                        
        (myPurge(cdr L)) ))))
```

Correctly indented/formatted/named:

```
(defun my-purge (list)
  (if (null list)
      nil
    (if (eql (first list) (second list))
        (myPurge (rest list))
      (progn
        (first list)
        (my-purge (rest list))))))
```

What looks strange? See the comment below.

```
(defun my-purge (list)
  (if (null list)
      nil
    (if (eql (first list) (second list))
        (myPurge (rest list))
      (progn
        (first list)                ; <- what does this do?
        (my-purge (rest list))))))
```

Bonus: you can get rid of the nested IFs:

```
(defun my-purge (list)
  (cond ((null list)
         nil)
        ((eql (first list) (second list))
         (myPurge (rest list)))
        (t
         (first list)
         (my-purge (rest list)))))
```

Comment: It should be returning like the `nil` above it? I am new to LISP , I am not sure. I tried to construct a new list but it told me the new list was undefined. Would that be a good route? I only have the primitive functions to work with.

Comment: Where should it return to? Currently the return value goes into Lisp-Nirvana. The PROGN returns the value of the last subform.

Comment: I rewrote the whole thing to use a predefined function i had. Here is that code.    `(defun myPurge (L)
        (if (eq L nil)
                nil
                (if(myMember(car L)(cdr L))
                        (myPurge(cdr L))
                (cons (car L)(myPurge(cdr L))))))))
`